# No segmentation fault if program running under gdb

Tags: gdb

I have a very strange problem for a custom program running under RHEL5 32bit.

This is a commercial program written in C, so I don't have source code. Anyway, I got segmentation fault (signal 11) randomly when I ran this program about 50% of time.  E.g. When I ran this program with the same parameters and conditions for 10 times, 5 times it gives signal 11, 5 times completed successfully.

I set the `ulimit` to unlimted to collect core dump. I was able to get the core dump file and fire gdb to see the backtrace. I can see where the program stops on which function is called before error.

I started this program under gdb:
gdb [program name], then enter "run [parameter1] [parameter2] ..."

Then I get "Program exited normally."

I got the result (a text file) without any problem.  Since this signal 11 happens in random, so I ran this program under gdb 100 times. **No error at all**.

I went back and run this program normally.  Core dump.

So my question is really simple:
What is the differences that I run this program normally and I run it under gdb ? I really can't figure out why it just run perfectly under gdb, but randomly give error under normal conditions.

```
$ uname -a
Linux vsapvm01 2.6.18-398.el5PAE #1 SMP Mon Sep 15 23:05:28 PDT 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: If you don't have source code, how do you expect to fix the program?

Comment: Your program probably has a buffer overrun or similar problem.  Having these issues means that your program has introduced *undefined behavior".

Comment: It's called a **heisenbug**, in relation to the fact that observing the bug makes it disapear just like some people understand the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle, which of course doesn't say that.

Comment: `I have a very strange problem for a custom program running under RHEL5 32bit.`   This is **not** a strange problem if you're talking about C or C++.  Unlike most other languages, programs in C or C++ that have these types of bugs do not run in a deterministic fashion.  You go outside the bounds of an array in, say Java, you get a stack dump.  In C or C++, your program may crash, may work, may crash sometimes and work other times, may work on your computer and crash on another computer, etc.  That is what is meant by **undefined behavior**.

Comment: The strange part is that it runs absolutely fine under gdb debugger but error out when it runs normally.  I just want to know what's the difference when a program runs under gdb, with all parameters and environment variables are the same.

Comment: Debuggers sometimes affect the memory layout - and hence cache utilisation patterns - of the program they load, or slow it down by adding some interception of exceptions, signals, certain library or OS function calls etc., or adding other instrumentation.   Such things can affect performance and therefore whether race conditions are "lost" in a way that causes a crash.  Intercepting/handling memory requests can lead to different padding or alignment.  That's vague, but I don't know details for gdb.  All the why's aren't so useful to know - bottom line is this stuff happens.

Comment: In addition to what Tony said, gdb could be zeroing memory, leading to checking an unintialised value behaving as expected under gdb but not otherwise (e.g. cheking an unintialised pointer for NULL).

Answer (score 4):

Debuggers can sometimes cause programs to behave differently. Here are some possible ways:

- A debugged program typically runs slower. This can hide *race conditions* between multiple threads; typically, these races are timing-dependent.
- GDB in particular weakens ASLR (address space layout randomization), meaning that programs are loaded with memory addresses that are more predictable or even fixed. This in turn means that bugs which touch bad memory might not crash under GDB if they "happen" to wind up touching valid addresses under GDB's fixed memory map.
- Some programs may explicitly behave differently if a debugger is attached, especially as an anti-reverse-engineering feature.

Any of these issues can cause a program to behave differently while being tested under GDB; bugs that disappear when investigated (e.g. with a debugger) are colloquially called [*heisenbugs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

---

So you wonder what could possibly cause a program to crash 50% of the time when run normally, but work every time under a debugger? Allow me to present this little gem, which on x86-64 Linux will crash with probability exactly 50% when run normally, but run successfully every time it is debugged: <sup>(at least, on my test machine)</sup>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int *x = malloc(256);
    printf("%d\n", *(int *)((unsigned long long)x & ~0x1000));
}
```

This exploits ASLR and the fixed memory map (point two above) - under randomization, clearing the 12th bit of `x` will crash the program half the time, but without randomization (under GDB) the 12th bit will always be clear all the time. (This is for illustrative purposes only; I do not claim that your software has such an obvious bug!)

Comment: you answer is bingo !  I turned off the ALSR by setting the kernel parameter "kernel.randomize_va_space=0" (originally it is default to 1) and now the program runs perfectly.  Thanks for your insightful reply and you really save my life!